# Vector Spaces and Simple Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $G$ be a ﬁnite group and let $R = \textbf{R}[G]$ be the group ring of $G$ with coeﬃcients in the ﬁeld $\textbf{R}$ of real numbers. Let $V$ be an $R$-module which is ﬁnite-dimensional as an $\textbf{R}$-vector space. How do I show that $V$ contains a simple $R$-module.

I am kind of lost here, however I know that that such a property is not true for an arbitrary ring $R$; for instance, $\textbf{Z}$ viewed as a module over itself contains no simple $\textbf{Z}$-submodules.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your notation has ambiguity. Use **R** for real numbers and $R$ for the group ring, **R**$[G]$.
Now any R-module is also an **R**-vector space. As we are working with finite-dimensional ones how about that $R$-module that has the least dimension as an **R**-vector space ?

Comment: Thanks, I already change the notation. With respect to your comment could you be more precise? thanks

Comment: Choose an $R$-submodule $W\subset V$  that has least possible dimension as an **R**-vector space. When we have a finite-dimensional vector space any proper subspace  has strictly lower dimension.